# Polynomials in Trouble

Tags: polynomials

Given the polynomial $ Q(n)=x^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+...a_{0}$

$Q(0)=34$      Suppose $Q(a_1)=Q(a_2)=...=Q(a_t)=55$, where $a_1,a_2,...a_t$ are distinct integers.

Find the maximum value of t.

To be honest, this is a question that a teacher has suggested me to do... This is what I started with:

I assumed that $a_1=a_{n-1},a_2=a_{n-2}...a_t=a_{0+1}$

Therefore $Q(a_1)=a_1^n+a_1^n+a_1^{n-2}a_2+...17$

$Q(a_1)=2a_1^n+a_1^{n-2}a_2+...17=20$

$Q(a_1)=2a_1^n+a_1^{n-2}a_2+...=3$

I am not sure if I should continue doing this for the other terms as well, and if my assumptions are true... Someone please recommend a way or possibly a book that I can use? Since all of the books are written in a very technical way that I cannot comprehend. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: If you factor $-21 = 34-55$ into a product of distinct integers, what is the maximum number of integers you can have?

Comment: Hmm, why -21? Anyway, the factors are (-1,21),(1,-21),(-3,7), and (3,-7). But why would that be helpful?

Comment: Another hint: $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_t)|Q(x)-55 \implies (-a_1)(-a_2)\cdots(-a_t)| -21$.

Comment: What's the | sign? Are we also assuming that the distinct integers are roots of the polynomial?

Comment: $a|b$ means $a$ divides/is a factor of $b$. $a,b$ can be integers or polynomials. $Q(a_1) = \cdots Q(a_t) = 55$ implies $a_1,\ldots,a_t$ are roots of the polynomial $Q(x) - 55$.

Comment: $a|b$ is read as "$a$ is divisible by $b$".

Comment: How can the $a_k$ be distinct and equal at the same time?

Comment: When you say "what is the maximum number of integers you can have" as in (-1)(21) (1)(-21) (-3)(7) (3)(-7), is this correct? So, the maximum number of integers is 8? Therefore implying that t=8? I am not sure xD

Comment: No, what I mean is in any factorization of $-21$, how many distinct factors one can have. the maximum number is $4$. eg. $-21 = 7\cdot 3 \cdot 1 \cdot -1$.

Comment: Why is it 4? Didn't we say that it's the product of distinct integers divisible by  -21, meaning you can even do -2 ⋅ 21= -42, which is divisible by -21? Or do you mean divisible as in it gives you just directly 1 after dividing by -21?

Comment: You are using $a_i$ as arguments of the polynomial, and also as coefficients of the polynomial. Is this what you mean? If not, please edit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=Q(x)-55$. We know that $f(a_i)=0$ for all natural numbers $i\leq t$ so we can write $f(x)$ as:

$$f(x)=k(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_t)$$

We also know that $f(0)=k(-a_1)(-a_2)\cdots(-a_t)=34-55=-21$

To **maximize** the value of $t$ we want as many distinct terms $a_i$ as possible which multiple together to give $-21$. This is achieved by $-21=7\cdot3\cdot1\cdot-1$. So there are 4 terms possible and $t=4$.

Comment: Ah alright I understand, but could you explain what f(ai)=0∀i∈ℕ,i≤t means? I've never seen this notation before lol :P

Comment: I changed it. $\forall$ is shorthand for "for all" while $i\in\mathbb{N}$ means that $i$ is an element of the natural numbers ($\mathbb{N}$ is the symbol for the set of natural numbers).